# Sign multiple PDF files at one go / Batch processing / iText7

Tags: c#, pdf, certificate, itext7, sign

I use iText7 (C#) to sign PDF files and it works very fine!

Now, I would like to sign more than one PDF file at one go using this or another library...
My certificate asks for pin, the idea is to sign multiples files setting the pin only one time.

Is this possible?